# LSI MegaRAID Storage Manager - Delete primary array

Tags: linux, raid1, megaraid, storcli

Situation: server contains two RAID-1 arrays; one primary for OS and one secondary for data.
My question is: If I delete primary array with command 
**/opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c# /v# del** 
what will be erased? Only MBR or whole disk with all data on it?
Thx

Comment: Why on earth should it only delete the MBR? It will delete your VirtualDrive.

Comment: So everything will be lost? Correct?

Comment: I don't know the complete implementation of the command, but assume that the VD will be gone _including_ the data. Maybe it will only delete the RAID metadata, you can probably look that up.

Comment: "If you delete a virtual drive with a valid MBR without erasing the data and then create a new virtual drive using the
same set of physical drives and the same RAID level as the deleted virtual drive, the old unerased MBR still exists at
block0 of the new virtual drive, which makes it a virtual drive with valid user data. Therefore, you must provide the
force option to delete this newly created virtual drive."

Comment: So it will not boot but data will be saved.

Comment: ...but you won't be able to access it if you don't recreate the RAID1.

Comment: A conclusion is that data will be preserved in one way.

Answer (score 0):

Test results: primary array is deleted with command **/opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c# /v# del**, than same array is recreated in RAID BIOS....no any data loss. OS is booting again from the recreated array with no issues.